# Printing an array without print_r tags php

Tags: php, arrays, count

Not sure if I am asking the correct question but I have an array with a couple "List" names and I want to count how many times they occur in the array and print it. Here is the list:

```
$array = ['EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_20160105', 'EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_20160105', 'EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_20150105', 'EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_30160105', 'EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_20160205', 'EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_20178105'];
```

I am currently using print_r and array_count_values to print and count through the array.

```
print_r(array_count_values($array));
```

My output is:

```
Array
(
    [IMC_UMP_WRAP_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANM_20160105] => 2
    [IMC_UMP_WRAP_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANM_20150105] => 1
    [IMC_UMP_WRAP_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANM_30160105] => 1
    [IMC_UMP_WRAP_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANM_20160205] => 1
    [IMC_UMP_WRAP_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANM_20178105] => 1
)
```

I would like to somehow get rid of the word "Array" and the parentheses. My ideal output would be:

```
[IMC_UMP_WRAP_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANM_20160105] => 2
[IMC_UMP_WRAP_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANM_20150105] => 1
[IMC_UMP_WRAP_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANM_30160105] => 1
[IMC_UMP_WRAP_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANM_20160205] => 1
[IMC_UMP_WRAP_ANNUAL_REVIEW_MANM_20178105] => 1
```

** Square brackets could be optional. thank you!

Comment: Little thing called `foreach`?

Comment: As stated above, did you try to loop with [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) ?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to iterate over your array (as mentioned in the comments above), try using `preg_replace` to get rid of the parts you don't need:

```
$array = array(
    'EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_20160105', 
    'EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_20160105', 
    'EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_20150105', 
    'EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_30160105', 
    'EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_20160205', 
    'EMC_IMP_PAT_ANT_REVIEW_MANG_20178105',
);
echo preg_replace(
    '/(^Array|^\\(\n|^\\)\n|^\s*)/m', 
    '', 
    print_r(array_count_values($array), true)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Foreach**

```
$data=array_count_values($array);

echo '<pre>';

foreach($data as $key => $value){

    echo '[' . $key . '] =>' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}

echo '</pre>';
```